# Converting SQl to laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to convert Sql query to laravel query . Daytabase used is postgresql

Laravel Query

```
$c_list = DB::table('cities')
             ->select('id as city_id', 'name as lang_name', 'ascii_name as city_name', 'iso2', DB::raw("(CASE WHEN iso2 = 'DE' THEN 'Germany' WHEN iso2 = 'CH' THEN 'Switzerland' ELSE 'India' END) AS codeCity"))
             ->whereIn('iso2', array('DE', 'IN', 'FR', 'TA', 'CH'))
             ->orderBy('codeCity','asc')
             ->orderBy('city_name','asc')
             ->get();
```

Showing error

> SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "codeCity" does not exist LINE 1:
>
> Output is getting when orderby codeCity is removed

*DataBase Schema*

[image]

Without orderby results are getting

```
$c_list = DB::table('cities')
             ->select('id as city_id', 'name as lang_name', 'ascii_name as city_name', 'iso2', DB::raw("(CASE WHEN iso2 = 'DE' THEN 'Germany' WHEN iso2 = 'CH' THEN 'Switzerland' ELSE 'India' END) AS codeCity"))
             ->whereIn('iso2', array('DE', 'IN', 'FR', 'TA', 'CH'))
             ->get();
```

Comment: post your table schema.

Comment: @Raptor Table Schema image added. Output is getting when orderby codeCity is removed

Comment: @viettel solutions Still showing error "SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "codeCity"". Output is getting when orderby codeCity is removed

Comment: @Raptor while print output after removing orderBy codecity. the results are getting and codeCity is there in output also

Answer (score 2):

You can use `selectRaw()` instead of `DB:raw()`:

```
DB::table('cities')
         ->select('id as city_id', 'name as lang_name', 'ascii_name as city_name', 'iso2') 
         ->selectRaw("(CASE 
                        WHEN iso2 = 'DE' THEN 'Germany' 
                        WHEN iso2 = 'CH' THEN 'Switzerland' 
                        ELSE 'India' 
                        END) 
                        AS codeCity")
         ->whereIn('iso2', array('DE', 'IN', 'FR', 'TA', 'CH'))
         ->orderBy('codeCity','asc')
         ->orderBy('city_name','asc')
         ->get();
```

**EDIT (for reply)**: So weird. But you can try another like this

```
DB::table('cities')
     ->select('id as city_id', 'name as lang_name', 'ascii_name as city_name', 'iso2') 
     ->whereIn('iso2', array('DE', 'IN', 'FR', 'TA', 'CH'))
     ->orderByRaw("CASE 
                    WHEN iso2 = 'DE' THEN 'Germany' 
                    WHEN iso2 = 'CH' THEN 'Switzerland' 
                    ELSE 'India' 
                    END",'asc')
     ->orderBy('city_name','asc')
     ->get();
```

Comment: Still showing error "SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "codeCity"". Output is getting when orderby codeCity is removed

Comment: @SatheeshKumar We reply in our answer (The comment is a little difficult to write code). You can try it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the query without orderBy statements and check if the output collection is empty or not.
One reason for this error could be an empty collection as a result. So make sure the query has any results.

Comment: Works fine without orderby. But I need Orderby

Comment: Would you please post your query output without orderBy?

Comment: Question updated pls check